# how to drop SSH establish connection that goes through linux gateway( router)?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

The diagram is as follows

```
Client (ssh root@192.168.0.254)->Linux Router(192.168.0.254 )-> host(192.168.0.69)
```

It seems that even if i close linux router(close port), connection is still establish (ps -ef inside host). 
I am not allowed to use killcx/any command inside host.

regards

Answer (score 0):

If you simply stop the flow of packets between client and server, then the ssh server has no way of telling that the client has gone away.

There is a workaround possible, in fact it should be enabled by default:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

in the sshd_config file.

Additionally, the option

```
ClientAliveInterval 10
```

kill cause an ssh packet to be sent every 10 seconds to the client; failure to respond to (by default) 3 consecutive packets will lead to the connection being closed.

Both options need to be set on the server.

Comment: Hi wurtel, thanks for replying, but i want a way to close that session using the linux router(HAProxy like Load Balancer) instead of changing the host program settings. i have a situation similiar to this case but im  not using haproxy. http://serverfault.com/questions/800237/force-haproxy-to-reset-tcp-connections-when-primary-server-comes-back-online